# What is the difference between bindParam and bindValue?

Tags: php, pdo, bindparam, bindvalue

What is the difference between [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation for [`bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

And [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

> call PDOStatement::bindParam() to bind PHP variables to the parameter markers: bound variables pass their value as input and receive the output value, if any, of their associated parameter markers

Example:

```
$value = 'foo';
$s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM bar WHERE baz = :baz');
$s->bindParam(':baz', $value); // use bindParam to bind the variable
$value = 'foobarbaz';
$s->execute(); // executed with WHERE baz = 'foobarbaz'
```

or

```
$value = 'foo';
$s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM bar WHERE baz = :baz');
$s->bindValue(':baz', $value); // use bindValue to bind the variable's value
$value = 'foobarbaz';
$s->execute(); // executed with WHERE baz = 'foo'
```

Comment: I feel the need to point out that the examples are taken from @lonesomeday's answer, and not the other way around, since there are no credits given in the answer.

Answer (score 719):

From [the manual entry for `PDOStatement::bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> [With `bindParam`] Unlike `PDOStatement::bindValue()`, the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that `PDOStatement::execute()` is called.

So, for example:

```
$sex = 'male';
$s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM students WHERE sex = :sex');
$s->bindParam(':sex', $sex); // use bindParam to bind the variable
$sex = 'female';
$s->execute(); // executed with WHERE sex = 'female'
```

or

```
$sex = 'male';
$s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name FROM students WHERE sex = :sex');
$s->bindValue(':sex', $sex); // use bindValue to bind the variable's value
$sex = 'female';
$s->execute(); // executed with WHERE sex = 'male'
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Question -- why might you want to use one over the other? Like when would it be useful or necessary to have the bind parameter evaluated only at execute() time?

Comment: @Coldblackice If you were executing the query multiple times with different data. With `bindValue` you'd need to re-bind the data each time. With `bindParam` you'd just need to update the variable. The main reason for using `bindValue` would be static data, e.g. literal strings or numbers.

Comment: For example, you want to use bindValue with function return values: $stmt->bindValue(':status', strtolower($status), PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: wanted to upvote, but because it is 666, I will leave it

Answer (score 232):

Here are some I can think about :

- With `bindParam`, you can only pass variables ; not values
- with `bindValue`, you can pass both (values, obviously, and variables)
- `bindParam` works only with variables because it allows parameters to be given as input/output, by "reference" *(and a value is not a valid "reference" in PHP)* : it is useful with drivers that (quoting the manual) :

> support the invocation of stored
>   procedures that return data as output
>   parameters, and some also as
>   input/output parameters that both send
>   in data and are updated to receive it.

With some DB engines, stored procedures can have parameters that can be used for both input (giving a value from PHP to the procedure) and ouput (returning a value from the stored proc to PHP) ; to bind those parameters, you've got to use bindParam, and not bindValue.

Comment: @PascalMartin Just what I wanted to know, can you bind values with bindParam. Cheers.

Comment: I still have no clue what that exactly means, what exactly are the variables and what are the values. I use bindParam to bind a value to a placeholder and with bindValue I can do the same! - in my example at least...

Comment: @Richard **Variables:** `$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);` **Values:** `$stmt->bindValue(':id', 1);`. Note if we replace `$id` with `1` in `bindParam` an error will be emited.

Answer (score 34):

From [Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Use `bindParam` to insert multiple rows with one time binding:

```
<?php

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 30):

For the most common purpose, you should use `bindValue`.

`bindParam` has two tricky or unexpected behaviors:

- `bindParam(':foo', 4, PDO::PARAM_INT)` does not work, as it requires passing a variable (as reference).
- `bindParam(':foo', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT)` will change `$value` to string after running `execute()`. This, of course, can lead to subtle bugs that might be difficult to catch.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#94711

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to put this into perspective for memorization by behavior (in terms of PHP):

- `bindParam:` *reference*
- `bindValue:` *variable*

Comment: bindValue takes a _value_.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to struggle any longer, when there exists a way lilke this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE col = :val");
$stmt->execute([":val" => $bind]);
```