# PDO->bindParam, PDO->bindValue and PDO->closeCursor

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindvalue, bindparam

So far I have been using `PDO->bindParam` however while reading the manual I found `PDO->bindValue` from what I can tell `PDO->bindValue` passes by value where as `PDO->bindParam` passes by reference, is this the only difference?

```
$modThread = db()->prepare("UPDATE `threads` SET `modtime` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) WHERE `threadid` =:id LIMIT 1");

while(something)
{
        $modThread->bindParam(':id', $thread);
        $modThread->execute();
//*******************HERE********************//
}
```

Again while reading the manual I found: `PDO->closeCursor` should I place it where marked? Is it optional/automatically called? Seems only certain drivers need it. Will calling it on a driver that doesn't need/support it cause errors? How about MySQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue gave some information about the first part (see the non-selected answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'recurring' `bindParam()` here is not really necessary:

```
$thread = 0;
$modThread->bindParam(':id', $thread);

while($thread < 20)
{
    $thread++;
    $modThread->execute(); //executing with the new value, which you couldn't do with bindValue
}
```

You don't need a `closeCursor()` when there is no resultset (i.e, only with `SELECT` s or procedures giving results back) , but usually I've already done a fetchAll somewhere in a previous statement / row.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't true.  If you find yourself needing to use closeCursor, one of the most optimal times is for insert/update/delete commands, and rarely for SELECT statements for which you have already fetched results.

For example, if you select all records from a table, then issue $stmt->fetch(), this actually accomplishes the goal for closeCursor immediately as the rows are now no longer in an unfetched status.

From the manual:

> This method is useful for database drivers that do not support executing a PDOStatement object when a previously executed PDOStatement object still has unfetched rows. If your database driver suffers from this limitation, the problem may manifest itself in an out-of-sequence error.

When you will really need closeCursor is during any of the following instances:

- If your DB driver doesn't allow for a new stmt to be executed while unfetched rows are available from the previous execute
- You have multiple prepared statements and would like to execute them one-after-another ($stmt1->execute(); $stmt->closeCursor(); $stmt2->execute(); $stmt2->closeCursor(); $stmt3...etc)
- You have multiple stmts that must execute insert/update/delete inside the same block.  This is true because, while you dont get mysql row results back, you DO get number of affected rows result set back (which is still a result).
- When using transactions
- When you want to issue select-style prepared statements and execute them, but not retrieve the data until later

When you don't need the closeCursor statement:

- If you have already fetched the rows (as with $stmt->fetch()) before your next statement is to be executed.  At this point the rows are in a "fetched" state and frees up the driver to execute new statements.

Just as useful for closing a cursor is unset() (ie: unset($stmt)) and setting the statement to null ($stmt = null), opening the doors for the built-in Garbage Collector to clear everything up.

See the manual for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php