# How to bulk change MySQL Triggers DEFINER

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've been working on our internal development server and creating MySQL Triggers on our MySQL 5.6.13 server.  The problem I now have is the Triggers (around 200 in total) were created with as DEFINER=`root`@`%` on the internal server.

Now I want to move to the live production server.  However on our live server we don't allow this access for user root.  Therefore how can I bulk change all my Triggers, so that it reads DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

One way to do it:

1) Dump trigger definitions into a file

```
# mysqldump -uroot -p --triggers --add-drop-trigger --no-create-info \
      --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt test > /tmp/triggers.sql
```

2) Open `triggers.sql` file in your favorite editor and use `Find and Replace` feature to change `DEFINER`s. Save updated file.

3) Recreate triggers from the file

```
# mysql < triggers.sql
```

Comment: On Mac I get the message "unknown option: --add-drop-trigger" on Mac OS X with Zend Server

Comment: This only works in some environments.  Doesn't work on community 5.5.36 on centOS... "mysqldump: unknown option '--add-drop-trigger'"

Comment: --add-drop-trigger was added in 5.6.0 - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-0.html

Comment: Pipe the results through this sed script: `sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/'`

Comment: I had to remove `--skip-opt` for this to work. Just if someone stumbles upon this. But very useful answer and still valid in 2021.

Comment: it never returns and stays running

Answer (score 6):

Run this sql statement (replace tablename and triggername with the desired triggers):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `', trigger_name, '`;', CHAR(13), 'DELIMITER $$', CHAR(13), 'CREATE TRIGGER `', TRIGGER_NAME, '` ', ACTION_TIMING, ' ', EVENT_MANIPULATION, ' ON ', EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA, '.', EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE, ' FOR EACH ROW ', ACTION_STATEMENT, '$$', CHAR(13), 'DELIMITER ;') AS command
FROM information_schema.triggers
WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA = 'tablename'
AND TRIGGER_NAME = 'triggername';
```

Then modify the result and execute it.

Comment: Actually it's not the tablename but instead dbname.

Answer (score 4):

Without using --add-drop-trigger option:

```
currentUserDefiner='root'
currentHostDefiner='localhost'
newUserDefiner='user'
newHostDefiner='localhost'
db='myDb'
mysqldump -u root --triggers --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt $db \
| perl -0777 -pe 's/(\n\/\*.+?50003 TRIGGER `([^`]+)`)/\nDROP TRIGGER \2;\1/g' \
| perl -0777 -pe 's/(DEFINER[^`]+)'$currentUserDefiner'(`@`)'$currentHostDefiner'/\1'$newUserDefiner'\2'$newHostDefiner'/gi' \
> out.sql
mysql -u root < out.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old post, but perhaps it can help someone.

I use this sql query to generate a DROP and a CREATE command:

```
SELECT CONCAT("DROP TRIGGER ", trigger_name, ";", " CREATE TRIGGER ", TRIGGER_NAME, " AFTER ", EVENT_MANIPULATION, " ON ", EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA, ".", EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE, " FOR EACH ROW ", ACTION_STATEMENT, ";") AS sqlCommand FROM information_schema.triggers WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA = "yourdatabase";
```

I use this in my app when I take the production database to my development machine and go it with a foreach over all commands and recreate the triggers automatically. This gives me the option to automate it.

Example in PHP/Laravel:

```
    $this->info('DROP and CREATE TRIGGERS');
    $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
    $sql = 'SELECT CONCAT("DROP TRIGGER ", trigger_name, ";", " CREATE TRIGGER ", TRIGGER_NAME, " AFTER ", EVENT_MANIPULATION, " ON ", EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA, ".", EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE, " FOR EACH ROW ", ACTION_STATEMENT, ";") AS sqlCommand FROM information_schema.triggers WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA = "mydatabase";';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    foreach($result as $rs){
        $pdo = DB::unprepared($rs['sqlCommand']);
        break;
    }
```

Hint: I have to do it with pdo because of the mysql buffer query problem, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434102/causes-of-mysql-error-2014-cannot-execute-queries-while-other-unbuffered-queries.)

The same I do for my views (Here you can use ALTER TABLE):

```
    $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
    $sql = 'SELECT CONCAT("ALTER DEFINER=`homestead` VIEW ", table_name," AS ", view_definition,";") AS sqlCommand FROM  information_schema.views WHERE table_schema="mydatabase";';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    $this->info('View definer changed');

    foreach($result as $rs){
        $pdo = DB::unprepared($rs['sqlCommand']);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Breaks "BEFORE" triggers. Otherwise nice.

Comment: Years late to the discussion here, but I'd change the query to do:

`SELECT CONCAT("DROP TRIGGER ", trigger_name, ";", " CREATE TRIGGER ", TRIGGER_NAME, " ",ACTION_TIMING," ", EVENT_MANIPULATION, " ON ", EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA, ".", EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE, " FOR EACH ROW ", ACTION_STATEMENT, ";") AS sqlCommand FROM information_schema.triggers WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA = "yourdatabase";`

This allows "BEFORE" triggers to work.

Comment: Had to further modify it so that `";"` in the above text becomes `";;"` I then wrapped all statements within `DELIMITER ;;` and at the end `DELIMITER ;`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me because most of my clients are hosted on servers with 5.5 and not much I can do about that, and the  [--add-drop-trigger function was added in 5.6](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34325)

After banging my head on this on, I just went in to phpMyAdmin which exposes the definer on the trigger edit page and I simply edited the definer for the 20 or so triggers that were wrong - phpMyAdmin will drop and recreate the trigger with the new definer.

Another option I found was to do a full mysqldump, edit the resulting file, use it to create a new database, then use a tool like Navicat to perform a structure sync back to the original database selecting only the desired triggers in the resulting compare list.  This was a much longer process for me because I only had to edit 20 triggers, but if I had to update hundreds of triggers this would be faster.

Comment: You could of course edit the file created by the dump and add the 'drop trigger if exists name-of-triger;'

Comment: Yep, but that's a bit more typing.  If I didn't have a good DB compare tool that would be how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use this Java utility. Note this is a work in progress as current version 1.0 clears some server variables.
[newdef](https://github.com/johnnyoh21/newdef)

Answer (score 1):

Another variation on the theme utilizing an option in MySQL Workbench is to dump the entire database using "mysqldump", open the dump in a capable editor, find replace with desired "DEFINER", then import with MyQSL Workbench with the "Dump Structure Option" (v6.2) selected on the import screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update the trigger definer by shutting down MySQL server, then updating the table .TRG files (those are text files, look for definer and CREATE DEFINER in them), and restarting MySQL. I only needed to do it for one table, but if there were many, I would have written a sed script or something along those lines. If the server cannot go down, the following should work quite smoothly with little disruptions to the activity (disclaimer - I had not tested it):

for each table:

- LOCK TABLE t WRITE
- FLUSH TABLE t
- do the sed magic on the TRG file
- UNLOCK TABLE t