# MySQL How to change trigger definer without recreating the trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

> I have no permission to take dump from live server.. More than 30
>   triggers here, I want update definer name without Recreating Triggers.

**Is it possible?**

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no ALTER TRIGGER statement in MySQL. DROP/CREATE is only way.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593746/how-to-bulk-change-mysql-triggers-definer
its may be helps.

Comment: @SagarGangwal I want to change or update triggers without recreating.