# Update trigger definer in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How to change definer in procedure and trigger using MySQL?

```sql
UPDATE `mysql`.`trig` p
    SET definer = 'user@%'
    WHERE definer='root@%'`
```

Comment: Have you looked up the _alter table_  syntax? You may have to drop and re-add the trigger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bulk change MySQL Triggers DEFINER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593746/how-to-bulk-change-mysql-triggers-definer)

Answer (score 1):

For Triggers and Views you can use this, as I have described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50943070/4820095). For Procedures the same thing should work with the table information_schema.routines.

Original Post:
I know it's an old post, but perhaps it can help someone.

I use this sql query to generate a DROP and a CREATE command:

```
SELECT CONCAT("DROP TRIGGER ", trigger_name, ";", " CREATE TRIGGER ", TRIGGER_NAME, " AFTER ", EVENT_MANIPULATION, " ON ", EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA, ".", EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE, " FOR EACH ROW ", ACTION_STATEMENT, ";") AS sqlCommand FROM information_schema.triggers WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA = "yourdatabase";
```

I use this in my app when I take the production database to my development machine and go it with a foreach over all commands and recreate the triggers automatically. This gives me the option to automate it.

Example in PHP/Laravel:

```
    $this->info('DROP and CREATE TRIGGERS');
    $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
    $sql = 'SELECT CONCAT("DROP TRIGGER ", trigger_name, ";", " CREATE TRIGGER ", TRIGGER_NAME, " AFTER ", EVENT_MANIPULATION, " ON ", EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA, ".", EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE, " FOR EACH ROW ", ACTION_STATEMENT, ";") AS sqlCommand FROM information_schema.triggers WHERE EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA = "mydatabase";';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    foreach($result as $rs){
        $pdo = DB::unprepared($rs['sqlCommand']);
        break;
    }
```

Hint: I have to do it with pdo because of the mysql buffer query problem, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434102/causes-of-mysql-error-2014-cannot-execute-queries-while-other-unbuffered-queries.)

The same I do for my views (Here you can use ALTER TABLE):

```
    $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
    $sql = 'SELECT CONCAT("ALTER DEFINER=`homestead` VIEW ", table_name," AS ", view_definition,";") AS sqlCommand FROM  information_schema.views WHERE table_schema="mydatabase";';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    $this->info('View definer changed');

    foreach($result as $rs){
        $pdo = DB::unprepared($rs['sqlCommand']);
    }
```

Hope it helps.