# Laravel - PDO Prepared Statement - Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I am having trouble running the following prepared statement in Laravel:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
$ps_TempTable_PushCsv = $pdo->prepare(
    "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '123'
    INTO TABLE `123`
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"
);
$ps_TempTable_PushCsv->execute();
$ps_TempTable_PushCsv->closeCursor();
$rowCount = $ps_TempTable_PushCsv->rowCount();
```

I get the following error:

> [2017-06-08 03:41:35] local.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

This is the entry-point of my controller, so there are definitely no prior queries running.

What do?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way I could get it working was to replace the prepared statement with an 'exec' call:

```
$rowCount = DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec(
            "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$fileName'
            INTO TABLE $tableName
            CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"
        );
```

I have no idea why it wouldn't work using a prepared statement in Laravel - it definitely does work with a pure PDO prepared statement.

Comment: You really should avoid grabbing the PDO handle and instead use something like `DB::insert` with a raw query.

Comment: One way to find out is to try it. As far as I know those handlers are pretty generic.

Comment: @tadman For what it's worth, `DB::insert` didn't seem to work for me in this type of situation. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: PDO::exec(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden

Answer (score 2):

If you go forward with [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426882/1531971), make sure to add the following code when creating your connection:

`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true`

For example:

```
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true
];
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DB, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, $options);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using DB::SELECT() to run raw queries.. In that case for INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE, it will hang for SELECT, so as per documentation You can simply use DB::INSERT('your insert query'), DB::UPDATE('your update query'),
DB::DELETE('your delete query')

It works for me...