# Is it possible to interrogate PDO to find out if queries are currently active?

Tags: php, pdo

*Is it possible to interrogate PDO to find out if queries are currently active ?*

ANSWER = **NO**

Try `setAttribute( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY , true);` just in case it works in your case

->closeCursor() after suspect verbs should help but you have to code around usage such as

```
return $pdoStatement->rowCount()===1;
```

Suspect verbs

```
->quote() Slight possibility if connection used like mysql_real_escape_string()
->query() High risk - use ->closeCursor()
->fetch() Highest risk - use ->closeCursor()
->fetchAll() should be safe but errors reported to Stack Overflow
->rowCount() **THIS** was causing my problem
```

To organise the bug hunt use debug_backtrace()
On line before FATAL ERROR

Use that list to backtrack execution adding ->closeCursor()
before each suspect verb line
save
test
if still getting FATAL ERROR fix the next verb one at a time

Once the errant line is discovered you can remove the debug_backtrace()

If that doesn't work I'm all out of ideas as the failure would have been created somewhere on the execution path.

---

These difficulties seem to be ignored by PHP PDO MySQL

Bug #70066  Unexpected "Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries"
Status = OPEN
Url = https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70066
Workaround = The solution is to use exec() instead of query(), but I think that it is bug since there is no other active query.

Bug #71145  Multiple statements in init command triggers unbuffered query error
Status = OPEN
Url = https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71145
Workaround = SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, SESSION sql_mode=traditional;

Bug #74584  Error about active unbuffered queries triggered unexpectedly
Status = OPEN
Url = https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74584
Description
An exception is thrown in the test case below.
 - Emulated prepares must be OFF
 - "LOCK TABLE" triggers the error, eg "set @foo='bar'" does NOT
I see no reason why the error occurs in this case.

---

> **IMPORTANT**
>
> The error generated is a FATAL ERROR
>
> This means that the program ->
>
> ...stops dead
>
> ...it cannot be handled with try(){}catch($e){} block

This would provide information to discover how to fix error

> "General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered
>   queries are active"

Hopefully this would short circuit looking through all the codebase to find the bug.

Currently I am trying to resolve this error being generated by

```
$statement = pdo->prepare( $sql );
```

Which means that the whole codebase is suspect

Why is this different to all other requests ?

NOTE: Error generated at prepare() stage

> NOT query()
>
> NOT fetch() and
>
> NOT fetchAll()
>
> NOT ->bind(':name' , $value , PDO::PARAM_STR)

Which means that I am not "executing a queries" when I get that message.

I'm asking because Stack Overflow has many requests on the error but no relevant solution

NOTE: Not Working

> $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY , true);
>
> $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY , false); // Just in case

Comment: PDO does not know about running queries, that you can check in your database server directly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434102/causes-of-mysql-error-2014-cannot-execute-queries-while-other-unbuffered-queries

Comment: ^ worth reading that one; the top answer was from the chap who literally wrote the book on SQL Antipatterns :)

Comment: try {
    $statement = pdo->prepare( $sql );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "PDOException ='".print_r($e,true)."'<br>\n";
}

Comment: try {
    $statement = pdo->prepare( $sql );
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "PDOException ='".print_r($e,true)."'<br>\n";
}

Still results in "Fatal error: Uncaught exception"

Doesn't make sense

Fatal errors are not trappable but message states "Uncaught exception"
Looks like it went from catchable to fatal due to missing catch(){}
BUT try()catch($e){} block exists