# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while there are pending result sets

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures, pdo

```php
$query = "CALL GetAllCategories()";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$categories = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I use this code to get categories from DB using stored procedures, no problems with that, everything works fine.

This is GetAllCategories() procedures:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetAllCategories`()
BEGIN
    SELECT
        id, name
    FROM
        categories ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

After that, I used regular SQL statement to get posts ( for testing, I will use stored procedure for that  )

this is the query to get posts:

```sql
SELECT
    `p`.`id`,
    `u`.`name` AS `author`,
    `post_title`,
    `post_date`,
    `post_img`,
    `post_content`
FROM
    `posts` `p`
JOIN `users` `u` ON
    `p`.`author_id` = `u`.`id`;
```

From here the problem occurred:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJz0Z.png)

this error appears:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while there are pending result sets. Consider unsetting the previous PDOStatement or calling PDOStatement::closeCursor() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\index.php:17 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\index.php(17): PDO->prepare('SELECT\n `p`....') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\index.php on line 17
```

When trying several attempts, I change the `GetAllCategories()` stored procedure to reqular query statement:

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
```

**The problem disappeared**

**Can anyone explain why this happed with stored procedures?**

**The last thing, After this issue, another problem appeared in the posts table when browsing it from PHPMyAdmin**

[posts table browsing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVzap.png)

Comment: This shouldn't happen if you use `fetchAll()`, as that's generally the way to *fix* this problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434102/causes-of-mysql-error-2014-cannot-execute-queries-while-other-unbuffered-queries for various suggestions

Comment: Try `$stmt->closeCursor();` after `fetchAll()`

Comment: So maybe because you're trying to use procedure with regular, So you should use all of your queries from one type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `$stmt->closeCursor();` after fetching data from `GetAllCategories()` stored procedure to solve this error.

```php
$query = "CALL GetAllCategories()";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$categories = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Answer (score 0):

*`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while there are pending result sets. Consider unsetting the previous PDOStatement`*

This error is always happens while there were two executions at a same time for example:

1. CASE 1

   if(!$query->execute())

   ```
   die("SQL FAILED");
   ```

   else

   ```
   $query->execute(); // **DELETE THIS ONE**
   ```

Solution: Second execution is no needed, remove second one, the first execution is already executed.

2. if the first case is not working, USE this Solution call this function after **$query=$handler->prepare($sql);**

   **$query->closeCursor();**

I hope this Solution is helpful