# What's the difference between PDOStatement->bindParam() and PDOStatement->bindValue()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDO: bindParam versus bindValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue)

What is a simple explanation of the difference between the two methods of [PDOStatement class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php): PDOStatement->bindParam() and PDOStatement->bindValue()?