# Using the LIKE operator with % for a keyword search with PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, sql-like

I am trying to write a keyword search using PDO prepared statements.  Ideally, I'd like to make use of the LIKE operator to search for a substring inside the field value.  Here is my code:

```
$statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from whatever where title like ? or author like ?");
$statement->execute(array("%$titleKeyword%","%$authorKeyword%"));
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Unfortunately, $rows is always empty when I try this.  However, if I copy the SQL into phpMyAdmin, and substitute '%keyword%' for each of the ? symbols, it works fine (I get results when the keyword used exists).

I have also tried the following code:

```
$statement = $this->db->prepare("select * from whatever where title like :titleKeyword or author like :authorKeyword");
$statement->bindValue(":titleKeyword",  '%'.$titleKeyword.'%',  PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(":authorKeyword", '%'.$authorKeyword.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I had read in another question that you are supposed to include the % when binding the parameters, not in the SQL itself (pre-prepared statement), but that doesn't work.

I could resort to just inserting the keyword directly into the SQL (after doing some sanitization), but I want to stick with prepared statements.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just done a quick mock of this and working fine (PHP 5.3.5) ~You definitely want to add your `%` when binding values. Maybe problems with your $titleKeyword & $authorKeyword?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I checked those before posting on here.

Answer (score 3):

This actually works for me:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from t where c like ?");
$stmt->execute(array("70%"));
print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
```

What PHP version do you use?

Comment: I'm using 5.3.1.  Even some comments on the PHP docs for PDOStatement suggest using one of those two methods.

Comment: Double check your variables $titleKeyword and $authorKeyword (use ```var_dump```!)

Comment: Already done (this is in a version where I modify the vars to have % before and after before I call bindValue):

string(6) "%iPod%" 

string(6) "%iPod%"

Comment: Are you using the same databases in PDO and phpMyAdmin? Then enable the mysql query log (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Steffen and Terry for the help.

I ended up solving the problem myself by switching to bindParam() instead of bindValue().  I am not sure why I couldn't do it with bindValue(), but right now I am just too tired to care.

Comment: Glad you figured it out Randy! further reading; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue