# Confusion between bindValue() and bindParam()?

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue, bindparam

I am confuse between these two functions `Bindvalue()` and `BindParam()`

1. I read on php.net it does not escape `%` and `_`, so be careful when using `LIKE`. So i think `BindValue()` is not used when we are using LIKE query.
2. when we using `LIKE` query `BindParam()` is used. Because as i know BindParam can escape these `%` and `_`.
3. `BindValue()` doesn't gives protection against sql injection. I am not sure about this, is it true?

friends tell what i mention in these 3 points is right or wrong.
i am beginner in PDO so please explain it clearly ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between bindParam and bindValue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There should be no difference in how values are escaped or not escaped. `bindParam` differs from `bindValue` in that it references the variable, binding the value only when you execute the statement. `bindValue` takes the *value* immediately. To illustrate:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE foo = :foo');

$foo = 'foo';
$stmt->bindValue(':foo', $foo);
$foo = 'bar';

$stmt->execute();
```

The above executes like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = 'foo'`;

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE foo = :foo');

$foo = 'foo';
$stmt->bindParam(':foo', $foo);
$foo = 'bar';

$stmt->execute()
```

The above executes like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo = 'bar'`.

It's true that neither cares about `_` or `%` as special characters, because generally speaking they aren't special characters as far as the syntax is concerned, and the database driver is not able to analyze the context to figure out whether you *mean* `%` to be a wildcard or the actual character "%" in the context of a `LIKE` query.

Both protect against SQL injection.

Comment: i want to know that bindValue() and bindParam() both gives protection against sql injection. i know it am asking stupid question but i am not sure about this that's why i am asking

Comment: Yes, they do. That's what I'm saying. You should read [The Great Escapism](http://kunststube.net/escapism) for details on what SQL injection is and why prepared statements avoid it.

Comment: @deceze `+1` for the good explanation. But, in what cases or at what point does it become important to use one instead of the other?  I just can see the reason why one should be suited to certain conditions, than the other.

Comment: @Simon By binding a variable by reference, you can bind it once, then loop through data, assign values to the variable and execute the query over and over without needing to repeatedly bind. May be slightly more efficient, but it mostly doesn't make any difference for performance. It may make code slightly cleaner though.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you took it all wrong.

`Bindvalue()` and `BindParam()` are equal in either way except for the argument type.

- Bindvalue() binds just a value, it's like a a *hard copy*.
- BindParam() binds a variable, and when a variable got changed, the binded value will be changed as well.

Both of them do not escape  % and _, which doesn't matter too much. Such escaping affects only  reliability of the returned results, not whatever "injections".