# Why is the reference needed to store the variable for BindParam?

Tags: php, pdo

I had an issue where I executed a stored procedure with variables:

```
INSERT INTO table_walkinleads
VALUES('', FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email, NOW())
```

but although this was working perfectly in phpmyadmin. It was not the case in my php code.

And the MAIN reason was because of this.

```
foreach($params as $name => $value ) {   
    $this->query->bindParam($name,$value);
}
```

Look carefully at the `$value` variable in the foreach statement. Before was like that. But after some investigation, I come to realize it needed to be `&$value`. But WHY? What is the difference? Why just adding that reference in the value variable makes the difference in making my stored procedure work correctly?

```
foreach($params as $name => &$value ) {   
    $this->query->bindParam($name,$value);
}
```

PS: the error was still executing the stored procedure, BUT the last variable was inserted as the same value for ALL the variables in the stored procedure. Making it look like I just entered the SAME variable for all the stored procedure variables.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior and the reason behind it?

Comment: You ought to use `->bindValue` here. `bindParam` is for output values, thus needs a referenceable variable (which the foreach always referring to the last loops value breaks due to a deferred execute). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413326/confusion-between-bindvalue-and-bindparam

Comment: makes sense the bindvalye method... but by just adding the reference it works like a charm with bindparam. I mean Its not big deal because it worked right? its all I needed, but my mind still wonders