# PHP PDO placeholders are replaced with the same values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PHP PDO show some inexplicable behaviour. The parameter placeholders are replaced with the same values.

$query

```
UPDATE `newsletters` SET `title` = :title , `scheduled` = :scheduled , `modified` = :modified WHERE `id` = :id
```

$parameter

```
Array
(
    [:title] => New Newsletter22
    [:scheduled] => 2013-04-15 21:47:00
    [:modified] => 2013-04-15 21:47:51
    [:id] => 35
)
```

The Function

```
public  static function execute($query=null,$parameters=array())
{
    global $dbnew;

    $statement= $dbnew->prepare($query);


        foreach($parameters as $k=>$v){
            if(is_array($v)){
                $statement->bindParam($k, $v[0],$v[1]);
            }else{
                $statement->bindParam($k, $v);
            }
        }


    $statement->execute();
    return $statement;
}
```

Executed query

```
1132 Query  UPDATE `newsletters` SET `title` = '35' , `scheduled` = '35' , `modified` = '35' WHERE `id` = '35'
```

Comment: You may want to use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`. Your foreach loop is overwriting the value of $v upon each iteration. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue

Comment: Yes, or pushing the values into an array.

Comment: Whenever something looks inexplicable to me in my PHP code, I more or less automatically go to the function/method page in the manual and double check all parameter, return-types, notes, warnings and user-comments. Most often then it's a short A-HA! and then back to coding.

Comment: @showdev Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bindParam` method binds a reference to a variable, rather than the value of the variable.

Your `foreach` loop updates the value of `$v` upon each iteration.

Since `bindParam` doesn't bind values until you actually execute the query, the value of all bound parameters in your example will be the same. They will all be bound to the value of `$v` from your last loop iteration.

Use `bindValue` to bind the actual value of the variable rather than a reference.

`$statement->bindValue($k, $v);`

From [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> **bool PDOStatement::bindParam**
>   Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder
>     in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the statement. Unlike
>     PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and
>     will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.