# PDO Prepared Statement Issue

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I have this prepared Statment:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from t where name like :name ");
```

Binding like this works:

```
$p = "%glas%";
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $p );
```

If I put in the term direktly, it fails:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':name', "%glas%" );
```

What´s the difference?

Comment: `"%glas%"` is not a variable - it can't bind to that.

Comment: For that, there's [`bindValue()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue

Comment: You can also simply pass an array of values to execute(), and this works for both lvalue variables and constant values. I'm always puzzled why people seem to think they need to bindParam() or bindValue() with PDO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [look at the method definition](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) for `bindParam`:

> public bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )

You will notice it expects `mixed &$variable` meaning it needs an *address*. When you pass a literal string, it is not stored with an address the way a conventional variable is.

The reason for the address requirement is also discussed in the documentation:

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.