# Why isn't PHP's "password_hash" returning a string?

Tags: php, php-password-hash

```
<?php
    $connection=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=userdata", "secure_credentials", "battery_staple");
    $user=$_POST['username1'];
    $pass=$_POST['password1'];
    $snip=mb_substr($user, 0, 3);
    $pass=password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $user_query=$connection->prepare("INSERT INTO login (email, password, semod, snippet) VALUES (:email, :password, :semod, :snippet)");
    $user_query->bindParam(':email', $user);
    $user_query->bindParam(':password', $pass);
    $user_query->bindParam(':semod', "false");
    $user_query->bindParam(':snippet', $snip);
    $user_query->execute;
```

(Password changed)

I'm facing a small problem with the above PHP code, whenever it's executed I get this error:

> **Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in** [location] **on line** [##: I shortened the above code... it's the password field with issues]

Looking around, this seems to be an issue when passing an string/integer *directly*, without using a variable. However, `password_hash()` returns a string, so I am led to believe that it's not returning a string. What could be the problem of this issue?

Comment: Wrong field, the issue is the `:semod` placeholder. You rare trying to pass a string literal (*"false"*) which cannot be used in `bindParam`. Use `bindValue` instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO: bindParam versus bindValue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue)

Comment: The error message has the line number in it. How did you end up thinking that the error was with `password_hash`, since I'll bet any amount that the line number points to the `:semod` line.

Comment: FYI - MySQL has a [boolean data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html#idm47351114471024) which would be a much better fit than the string *"false"* which is truthy in nature

Comment: @Phil Oops, if nothing else it shows that the error messages are on the "array scheme" (starting with 0).

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson no, they aren't. File line numbers in error messages are not zero-based indexes

Comment: @Phil I meant the "parameter 2", not the file line.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson It's referring to the second argument (ie *"parameter 2"*) that you've passed to `bindParam`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is on this line:

```
$user_query->bindParam(':semod', "false");
```

You need to use `bindValue`.

```
$user_query->bindValue(':semod', "false");
```

`bindParam` passes the second argument by reference, so it has to be a variable, not a literal.

Additionally, known values don't need to be bound. You could have just as easily added the literal `'false'` string to your statement query, ie

```
"INSERT INTO login (email, password, semod, snippet) VALUES (:email, :password, 'false', :snippet)"
```

Comment: Just as a btw, is there any point in using bindParam for an input only parameter in the first place?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Handy in a loop where the bound reference value may change.

Comment: If you mean is there any point in using it for a hard-coded parameter, not much. But it can make the query easier to read.

Comment: @Barmar You should add that (hard-coded parameters) to your answer. It's definitely worth pointing out that known values don't need binding

Comment: @Barmar Hope you don't mind, I added it to your answer for you. Then I upvoted. It felt kinda weird :)

Comment: @Phil FYI, when I review suggested edits, I usually reject edits like yours.