# How to get a proper error from PDO general error on insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, error-handling

I'm trying to inert into some table, and i get the genral error. Here's my code below.

NOTE: I used this very connection on another update query and it works fine.

Another thing, What's the difference between bindParam() and bindValue() ?

```
$query = $dbh->query("INSERT INTO music SET
                      uid = ?,  title = ?,
                      album = ?, artist = ?,
                      year = ?, genre = ?,
                      albumart = ?, audio = ?,
                      time = ?, perms = ?
 ");    


$query->bindParam(1, $uid);
$query->bindParam(2, $title);
$query->bindParam(3, $album);
$query->bindParam(4, $artist);
$query->bindParam(5, $year);
$query->bindParam(6, $genre);
$query->bindParam(7, $art);
$query->bindParam(8, $song);
$query->bindParam(9, now());
$query->bindParam(10, $download);
$query->execute();

$check_exc = $query->execute();

if ($check_exc) {
    $new_id = $dbh->lastInsertId('sid');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a mysqli function with PDO?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: For your second question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue

Comment: You should be using `$dbh->prepare()`, not `$dbh->query()`.

Comment: prepare, i ddnt see that, maybe that's where the error comes from.

Comment: That's definitely where the error comes from. The `?` placeholders are not allowed in an ordinary query, only when preparing.

Comment: nice, thanks. I have more than one downvote, hope others tell me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `prepare` instead of `query` call.
2. If it is PDO, use PDO error handler and not the `mysqli` one.
3. For differences between `bindParam` and `bindValue`, a [previous duplicate](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue) exists.

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO music SET
                      uid = ?,  title = ?,
                      album = ?, artist = ?,
                      year = ?, genre = ?,
                      albumart = ?, audio = ?,
                      time = ?, perms = ?");
if( !$query ) {
    die( print_r($dbh->errorInfo()) );
}
```

Comment: Ok this is good that for that prepare correction, i ddnt remove it yet, i want to try and get the right error from that instead of the general one. I'll accept this answer.

Comment: i didn't know this is also a valid mysql insert syntax, i though this format is only allowed: `INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1,col2) VALUES(?, ?)`

Comment: @user3109875 maybe for some fuzzy users haha, no prob for me, every one makes mistakes at some time. my votes are exhausted anyway