# PDO MYSQL output false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have code select database and output false.

but the usname and pasword my entry is true on database. and i used wamp server 64b. apache:2.49, php: 5.5.1.2. i open extension on php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll


public static function getByNamePass( $username, $password ) {
        $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM district_account WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";
        $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
        $st->bindValue( ":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->bindValue( ":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $st->execute();
        $row = $st->fetch();
        $conn = null;   
        if ( $row ) return new District_Account( $row );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `bindParam()`

```
$st->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindParam(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR );
```

Comment: Dang, beat me to it. +1.

Comment: thank you, but i var_dump and output true. code 
var_dump($st->bindValue( ":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR ));
output: boolean true

Comment: $st->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindParam(":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR );

output -> false

Comment: @phuochq I have just tried in my local environment, and bindParam output true. Maybe you should check your `$th` and `$conn`, check your connection

Comment: @phuochq Try `$sql = "SELECT * FROM district_account`, and without bind to see whether you have the results

Comment: Changing to bindParam in this case will make [no difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue).

Comment: output -> false

code 

`$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM district_account ";

    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
   //  $st->bindParam( ":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   // $st->bindParam( ":password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR );

    $st->execute();
    var_dump($st->execute());`

Comment: @phuochq It means that `execute()` returns false. Now you can `print_r($st->errorInfo());` after execute to see what is the error, maybe in the database

Comment: ok. thanks #iatboy. i have to find bug out connect :). thank thank

Comment: @phuochq No thanks, you mean error in the connection?