# Can't get SQL BETWEEN to work in PHP using Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get mySQL to send me posts between two dates. Since the dates are user input I use Prepared Statements. The query I use looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM butiken_orderregister
WHERE datum_skapad BETWEEN :datum_skapad_0 AND :datum_skapad_1
ORDER BY datum_skapad LIMIT 9999;
```

- :datum_skapad_0 = **2014-10-20**
- :datum_skapad_1 = **2014-10-23**

The column *datum_skapad* is in date format.

The query runs fine, but only returns posts where the column matches :datum_skapad_1. However, when I use MySQL Workbench I can get the results I want by using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM butiken_orderregister
WHERE datum_skapad BETWEEN "2014-10-20" AND "2014-10-23"
ORDER BY datum_skapad LIMIT 9999;
```

To me, these should be equivalent, but I evidently don't get the same results. I've tried using parenthesis like this:

```
SELECT * FROM butiken_orderregister
WHERE (datum_skapad BETWEEN :datum_skapad_0 AND :datum_skapad_1)
ORDER BY datum_skapad LIMIT 9999;
```

but it changes nothing.

Is there an obvious mistake I've made here or could the problem lie somewhere else?

#### Addendum:

This is the PHP that takes care of binding the parameters:

```
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($flat_data as $field => $value) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':' . $field, $value);
        $out .= ':' . $field . ' = ' . $value . "\n";
    }
    if ($return_query) {
        $out = $sql . "\n\n" . $out . "\n\n";
    } else {
        try {
            $stmt->execute();
            $out = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch(PDOException $error) {
            $out = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

`$flat_data` is an array with all values and the names I've used for them in the SQL. `$con` is a PDO object.

Comment: check your mysql logs, what do they say? Do you get an error?
<br />
Also: :datum_skapad_0 = '2014-10-20' and :datum_skapad_1 = '2014-10-23' do not forget apostrophes ;)

Comment: what does var_dump show on the variables ?

Comment: Adding apostrophes makes the query return nothing at all. But apostrophes shouldn't need to be used when using prepared statements anyway, right?

Comment: that is right but can't hurt to try... so what does the logs say?

Comment: I can't seem to access the logs. MySQL Workbench crashes when I try to open them through there and the file I get from `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log_file%';` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: `var_dump()` shows `string(10) "2014-10-20"` and `string(10) "2014-10-22"` for the two variables. This was checked right before binding the values.

Comment: @Szandor and before the execute ? The variables are not used until execute

Comment: I suggest that you try using 'bindValue' rather than 'bindParam': [questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue)

Comment: I tried using `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()` as Ryan Vincent suggested and it seems to work perfectly. I am still not clear on exactly why since I don't do anything to the variables (that I know of, at least) before I execute the statement, but now I know more about prepared statements and what to look for next time. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following comment by Ryan Vincent solved my issue:

> I suggest that you try using 'bindValue' rather than 'bindParam': questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue – Ryan Vincent Oct 23 at 17:06

If you write your comment as an answer, Ryan, I can mark it as the accepted one. Until then I'll mark this one.

I really can't find that I'm changing the variables between my binding and my execution though, but since this solved my issue I suppose it is just one of those PHP quirks. It's a strange and wonderful language...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try explicitly converting the col and parameters to dates, are you using date or datetime?

```
SELECT * FROM butiken_orderregister
WHERE (
    datum_skapad BETWEEN 
    DATE(:datum_skapad_0) AND DATE(:datum_skapad_1)
)
ORDER BY datum_skapad LIMIT 9999;
```

another way to cast dates:

```
SELECT * FROM butiken_orderregister
WHERE (
    datum_skapad BETWEEN 
    CAST(:datum_skapad_0 AS DATE) AND CAST(:datum_skapad_1 AS DATE)
)
ORDER BY datum_skapad LIMIT 9999;
```

Maybe the problem is with how PHP handles the parameters, you should post the PHP code where you do this.

Comment: This returns the same as before: only records matching the last date.

Comment: try the second cast method I've added

Comment: Same thing with the second one, unfortunately, but now I know how to cast data types in SQL :-). I've posted the PHP I use to bind the values in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @exussum, check the variables. Also check the column types and date format used.

Answer (score 0):

Might not resolve the issue but I would avoid using `BETWEEN`.

Instead use (for your example) `Date >= '2014-10-20' and Date < '2014-10-24'`

[More info on why](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)