# PDO prepared statement not behaving as expected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Given `$foobar = 'a'`, The following `bindParam` lines fail:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':foobar', 'C' . $foobar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

and

```
$stmt->bindParam(':foobar', "C$foobar", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Both of these return:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference
```

**In contrast**, this works fine:

```
$_foobar = 'C' . $foobar;
$stmt->bindParam(':foobar', $_foobar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Why is PDO not allowing me to concatenate a string in `bindParam`?

Comment: *Probably* because `char` is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - Most likely why and how you're using it elsewhere in your query which isn't shown, so that's a possibility.

Comment: Do you understand what "pass-by-reference" is? Use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam` unless you need that specific behaviour.

Comment: @Fred, "char" is just my example text.  The variable name is something else.  I will update the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Then it's as DCoder said. People do use reserved words in their query.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate per se, but the answers to it should illuminate what's wrong here.

Comment: DCoder has me pointed on the right track. I'm reading this question now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/pdo-bindparam-versus-bindvalue

Comment: Oh, so now it's `:foobar` lol / That's a big Ten-four.

Comment: I'm learning PDO - newb mistake.  Thanks.