# Prepared Statements with PDO doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I did some research around and I found two ways to prepared my statements from PDO object. But it seems like both are not working at all. I am missing something?

**Named placeholders**

```
$email = 'my_email';
$code = 'my_private_code';
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=personal_info;dbname=personal_info', 'personal_info', 'personal_info');
$sql = "UPDATE `promo` SET code = :code WHERE email = :email";
$st = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$st->execute(array(
   ':code' => $code,
   ':email' => $email
));
```

**Unamed placeholders**

```
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=personal_info;dbname=personal_info', 'personal_info', 'personal_info');
  $st = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO promo (`email`, `code`) VALUES (?, ?)");
  $st->bindParam(1, $email);
  $st->bindParam(2, $code);
  $email = 'my_email@hotmail.com';
  $code = 'my_private_code';
  $st->execute();
```

Comment: Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Plus, use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam` and check your column types.

Comment: `mysql:host=personal_info` that should be `mysql:host=localhost` (or whatever you've been given to use as the host) and not your database name. Fixing that may very well fix both your codes. Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Excellent, merci! Je crois que bindValue a fait effet :) Non ce n'est pas la mienne, j'y travaille comme back-end developper! Merci beaucoup Fred.

Comment: De rien, donc tout fonctionne?

Comment: Oui parfaitement, je peux continuer a coder! Merci pour ton aide Fred, on se reverra dans les meandres de l'informatique.

Comment: Tres bien Matthieu; c'a m'a fait plaisir, au revoir. *Arrivederci*

Comment: Voici un article que tu peux lire sur Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/1179874/