# bindParam causes a fatal error

Tags: php, pdo

I have this sql statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.creating_user FROM cdiscount_listing AS c WHERE c.created_at > :before_not_keyword AND c.created_at < :after_not_keyword";
    $query = $db->query($sql);

    $query->bindParam(":before_not_keyword", $date." 23:59:59", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(":after_not_keyword", $date." 00:00:00", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $listings = $query->fetchAll();
```

Which gives the standard `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation` error. However, when I hardcode the param values into the query instead the error goes away. Is there a bug in PDO itself or have I missed something here?

Note that the dates are being created like this for consistency with legacy code.

The date format: `2015-07-01 00:00:00`

Comment: What's `$date`? As in add it to the question.

Comment: replace `$db->query` with `$db->prepare`

Comment: Also parameters have to be bound by reference - I'm pretty sure `$date." 00:00:00"` as a parameter isn't going to work.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently its been longer than I thought since I used PDO last. Had the prepare and the binding by reference wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `bindParam()`, you must pass second parameter by **reference**, but you use string (not varaible), which can not be passed by reference.

So you can use `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In `bindParam()` the second parameter should be a reference ($variable), If you want to use second parameter as value you can do that using `bindValues()`

For eg using `bindParam()`:-

```
$before_date = $date." 23:59:59";
$after_date = $date." 00:00:00";
$query->bindParam(":before_not_keyword", $before_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(":after_not_keyword", $after_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

For eg using `bindValues()`:-

```
$query->bindValue(":before_not_keyword", $date." 23:59:59");
$query->bindValue(":after_not_keyword", $date." 00:00:00");
```

Find the difference between bindValue and bindParam() [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue?rq=1)