# INSERT using PDO prepared statements fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert values using prepared statements like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_table (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:tname, :tname2)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt -> bindParam(':tname', 'John');
$stmt -> bindParam(':tname2', 'Smith');
$stmt -> execute();
```

However, this is throwing a fatal error: "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/live/test_create.php on line 53" This is referring to this line: `$stmt -> bindParam(':tname', 'John');`

What's causing this problem?

Comment: Is that space meant to be there? Or is that formatting error?

Comment: @Script47 Which space?

Comment: `$stmt -> bindParam(':tname', 'John');
$stmt -> bindParam(':tname2', 'Smith');
$stmt -> execute()` I see that, a bunch of spaces after the `$stmt` variable.

Comment: @Script47 Sorry, still not sure which spaces you're talking about. Before `'John'` or somewhere else? I tried the code above as you have it and that yielded the same error.

Comment: Check my answer. Oh and this image wll show you what I mean about the spaces. http://i.imgur.com/bcm4uMk.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `bindParam` it must be passed by reference.

Use `bindValue` instead, for the way you are trying to use it here.

More about `bindValue` vs `bindParam` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue)

If you are insistent about using `bindParam`, it must be supplied as a variable. So you would use `$var1="John"` and then `$stmt->bindParam(':tname',$var1);`

Comment: I just learn't something new.

Comment: I actually am planning to use variables like `$thisthing`, but was doing the other as a test to make it simpler (which didn't work). Your solution was just what I needed. Thanks for the extra information about `bindParam` and `bindValue`.

Comment: No worries ... Take a read on that link though, as it shows that if you use `bindParam` you can actually change the value of the variable (after the bind, but before the execute), without it effecting the executed query.