# Why use bindparam rather than execute when both work, even when using ints with exectute

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to PDO, I know with execute you send the value as a string, but when you bind param you can define what it is, but no mater what my queries always work when sending them via a string via an execute, so what is the point (there is one I am just trying to figure what is it) of using bind param.

For example:

```
$insert_whatever = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO test(blah, blah1) VALUES (?, ?)");
$insert_whatever->bindparam('1', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert_whatever->execute(); 


$insert_whatever = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO test(blah, blah1) VALUES (?, ?)");
$insert_whatever->execute(array('1','1'));
```

Comment: There's a few places where the implicit type coercion in SQL doesn't work. For instance with the `LIMIT` clause in mysql.

Comment: @mario so it depends on the sql server whether to use bindparam or execute?

Comment: What if you want to limit your results as @mario has mentioned. You will need to define the bound value as an integer in that case bind is the option for that.

Comment: @rehmat do you have an example, please?

Comment: @Iamnotyou Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Execute fails sometimes. For example if you want to `LIMIT` your results returned from MySQL, then you will need to `Bind` parameters / values instead of passing them with execute command.

i.e.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ?, ?");
```

You will do:

```
$query->bindParam("1", 1, PDO::PARAM_INT) // assuming that you want to start from 1
$query->bindParam("2", 10, PDO::PARAM_INT) // assuming that you want to stop at 10
```

and then execute:

```
$query->execute();
```

If you are going to attach an integer value from a variable, then you will need to bind it as a value:

```
$query->bindValue("1", $variable, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Hint: `bindValue` works for all. Learn more about `bindParam` and `bindValue` here:
[What is the difference between bindParam and bindValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue)