# PDOException SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to take entries via a registration form using php. But I'm getting following error:

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1'

Here is my code:

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$name   = trim($_POST['name']);
$contact= trim($_POST['contact']);
$email  = trim($_POST['email']);

if(!empty($name) && !empty($contact) && !empty($email)){

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql::host='localhost';dbname=majorproject;",'root','');
        //for error reporting and throwing exceptions
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



        $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into #_customerdata(customername,customercontact,customeremail) values(:name,:contact,:email)"); 

        $stmt->bindParam(':name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':contact',$contact,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            header('location: ../customersignup.php?status=success');
        }
        else{
            header('location: ../customersignup.php?status=failed');
        }


    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'CONNECTION NOT ESTABLISHED '.$e;

    }





}

}
```

I have checked my code but couldn't find any errors.. Any suggestions to solve this problem??

Comment: that pound sign `#_customerdata` is the issue. wrap it in ticks `\`` or rename it without one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : i think your comments should be an answer. I'd add an answer, but you already provided the answer.  But kudos to OP... I'd hate to close this question...  OP is using PDO and not the deprecated mysql_ functions, and OP is using prepared statement with bind placeholders. Personally, I'd use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam` in this context.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue)

Comment: @spencer7593 It has been done and quoting your comment, *cheers*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested.

The `#` sign in your table name `#_customerdata` should be escaped using ticks.

```
insert into `#_customerdata`
```

Read up on Identifier Qualifiers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Assuming that is indeed the table's name and that the `#` sign doesn't represent a numerical value.

Either that, or rename it without it containing any characters that MySQL would complain about.

If it still complains about it, then you will have no choice but to rename it to just `customerdata`.

Also as stated in comments by [spencer7593](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107744/spencer7593):

*OP is using PDO and not the deprecated mysql_ functions, and OP is using prepared statement with bind placeholders. Personally, I'd use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam` in this context. [What is the difference between bindParam and bindValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue)*

and remove one of the colons here `mysql::host`.

Consult the manual on connecting with PDO:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Example from the manual:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
?>
```

---

Footnotes:

You should add an `exit;` after each header, otherwise your code may want to continue to execute.

```
if($stmt->execute()){
    header('location: ../customersignup.php?status=success');
    exit;
}
else{
    header('location: ../customersignup.php?status=failed');
    exit;
}
```

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Then the rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: +10. MySQL identifiers (e.g. table names, column names) that don't follow the naming rules *must* be properly escaped. Normative pattern in MySQL is to use the backtick character. (If `sql_mode` includes ANSI_QUOTES, then double quotes can also be used to escape identifiers.)  It's allowed to use an underscore as the first character of a table_name, without escaping. (For "work", "extract" and "save" tables that aren't part of the regular schema, but in the same database, I start the names of all of those with an underscore. That nicely separates them from the normal schema tables.)

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks for everything. Your comments included. I was going to add a link to MySQL's identifier qualifiers URL, which I'll do now. Edit: Added.

Comment: when you write a book, let me know, and I will buy it.

Comment: @spencer7593 You got it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If not working yet, try fixing this:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql::host='localhost';dbname=majorproject;",'root','');
```

Between 'mysql' and 'host' you have '::', but it should be ':'