# Not able to insert Null into database from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert NUll into database everything is working fine but null is not inserted.

below query for the same.

```
#update permissions for deleted user and make it to NULL
$edit_user_permission = $conn->prepare('update create_user set permission = ? where role_id = ?');
$edit_user_permission->bind_param("ss",$permission,$role_id);
$permission = NULL;
$role_id = $_SESSION['role_code'];
$edit_user_permission->execute();
```

below structure of Permission column in the database[image]

Comment: Have you tried `$permission = ""`

Comment: @hungrykoala `""` is not `NULL`.

Comment: Is your table created to accept NULL values?

Comment: You bind the values first and than set them? use `$permission = NULL;
             $role_id = $_SESSION['role_code'];$edit_user_permission->bind_param("ss",$permission,$role_id);
`

Comment: @Jens No, OP is binding the parameter (pass by reference, not value), so you can declare the values later, but just before executing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue

Comment: yes i have tried by doing $permission = " " but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I thing the issue is in parameter binding.So just change the parameter binding format.Do something like this

```
$edit_user_permission = $conn->prepare('update create_user set permission = ? where role_id = ?');
$edit_user_permission->bindParam(1, $permission);
$edit_user_permission->bindParam(2, $role_id);
$permission = NULL;
$role_id = $_SESSION['role_code'];
$edit_user_permission->execute();
```

It will help you.
You can refer [prepared-statements.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

**Modified**

```
$edit_user_permission->bind_param(1, $permission);
$edit_user_permission->bind_param(2, $role_id);
```

Try this one.

Comment: i'm getting error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam()

Comment: is it working for other value and not working for null.

Comment: i havt tried for other values but it is not working for null

Comment: then you do like this $permission = ' ';.And some me the table value after update