# Symfony raw sql query returns empty array

Tags: symfony, doctrine

When I'am passing $id variable in `bindValue('id', $id)` it shows empty array but when I pass number in `bindValue('id', 2)` ,I'm getting the result in array.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT s.subtitle FROM submenu as s where s.menu_id= :id");
$statement->bindValue('id', $id);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
dump($results);
```

Please could anybody tell me whats my mistake in above code. I am getting empty result if I pass variable in `bindvalue` function but if I use this `bindValue('id',2)` I'm getting result.

Comment: Did you try to `dump($id)` before `$connection` for example?

Comment: yes I have tried and I am getting $id value also before $connection

Comment: try this: `$statement->bindValue('id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT)` and also read this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue (maybe it will help you)

Comment: I tried but  still  result is empty

Comment: Strip your SQL to the minimum "SELECT s.* FROM submenu as s" and remove the bind value. Maybe you can further from this point if its working :)

Comment: please could you explain in a bit more details.if I remove bind value then could you tell me where I have to use $id variable to get result

Answer (score 0):

If $id is an integer the it should work but if not then may be some whitespace is coming in your variable (for example $id = ' 4redtr54r')
In this case you will get null value so can you please check your variable before assigning or use trim() function

```
$statement->bindValue('id', trim($id));
```