# bindParam/bindValue not working with my SQLite3 prepared statements

Tags: php, sqlite, php-7

Why is bindParam/bindValue not working with my SQLite3 prepared statements?
I have tried both `$stmt->bindValue` and `$stmt->bindParam`.

This doesn't work:

```
$user = "exampleUser"
$db = new SQLite3('example.db');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='?'");
if (!$stmt) {
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();;
    return false;
}
$stmt->bindParam(1, $user);
$result = $stmt->execute();
echo '<br>';
var_dump($result->fetchArray());
```

Neither does this:

```
$user = "exampleUser"
$db = new SQLite3('example.db');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=':user'");
if (!$stmt) {
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();;
    return false;
}
$stmt->bindParam(":user", $user);
$result = $stmt->execute();
echo '<br>';
var_dump($result->fetchArray());
```

But this does work:

```
$db = new SQLite3('example.db');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='exampleUser'");
if (!$stmt) {
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();;
    return false;
}
$result = $stmt->execute();
echo '<br>';
var_dump($result->fetchArray());
```

Comment: Why you not using `$db->lastErrorMsg();`? `echo 'prepare statement failed';` is almost as bad as no error at all.

Comment: Thanks, will update that. I am not so familiar with PHP/SQLite3

Comment: np, before you go any further you might want to use PDO instead, as later on you may want to use something other than sqlite, which PDO supports anyway. If your just learning the SQLite3 API for the sake of it then carry on. ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not string literals.

`'?'` should be `?` and `':user'` should be `:user`, without single quotes.

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept your answer in 8 mins. For future reference, the PDO bindParam/bindValue requires the `:` before named variable ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue)), SQLite3 does not.