# Query only responding to one tag

Tags: php, mysql, rest, http, get

I have this get URL response

```
http://localhost/../qry/radius.php?lat=48.366591&lng=10.899801&radius=50&tags=mexican,italian
```

im filling this query with given information

```
SELECT o.id, o.title, o.icon, o.description,
    (
        6371 * acos
        (
            cos(
                radians( :lat )
            )
            * cos(
                radians( lat)
            ) * cos(
                radians( lng) - radians( :lng )
            ) + sin(
                radians( :lat )
            ) * sin(
                radians( lat)
            )
            )
            ) AS distance
            FROM objects o, category_object co, category c
            WHERE o.id = co.id_object AND co.id_category = c.id AND (c.title=:title1 OR c.title=:title2) HAVING distance/1000 <= :radius
            ORDER BY distance/1000 ASC;
```

Php Code

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare($qry);

    $stmt->bindParam(":lat", $latitude);
    $stmt->bindParam(":lng", $longtitude);
    for($i=1; $i<sizeof($tags_list) + 1; $i++) {
        $input = $tags_list[$i-1];
        $stmt->bindParam(":title" . $i, $input);
    }        
    $stmt->bindParam(":radius", $radius);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

            $subquery = "SELECT c.title AS title FROM category c, category_object co, objects o
                         WHERE c.id = co.id_category AND co.id_object = o.id AND o.id=:id";

            $substmt = $db->prepare($subquery);

            $substmt->bindParam(":id", $result->id);

            $substmt->execute();

            $tagsForJson = "";
            while ($subresult = $substmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $tagsForJson = $tagsForJson . "," . $subresult['title'];
            }
            $tagsForJson = trim($tagsForJson, ",");

            echo json_encode(array("type" => "FeatureCollection",
                "features" => array(
                    "type" => "Feature",
                    "geometry" => array("type" => "Point",
                        "coordinates" => [$latitude, $longtitude]),
                    "properties" => array(
                        "ID" => $result->id,
                        "icon" => $result->icon,
                        "tags" => [$tagsForJson],
                        "title" => $result->title,
                        "description" => $result->description))), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
            echo "\n\n";
        }

    }
```

The Problem is that the query only returns results related to the last tag only, it ignores the tag 'mexican' completely.
**I have tested the query in my phpmyadmin and it works completely fine**, thats why I suspect the code around bindParam to be the problem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: your for loop is confusing, why not start at 0 and just increment ? Have you tried outputting inside the loop to make sure you are creating the placeholders and binding the values correctly?

Comment: also, what happens if more than 2 tags get passed - you will then have an invalid number of variables error because you hard code the placeholders

Comment: @jameson2012 I havent added the way I concat the query since the problem is not there, and I have debugged the bindParam loop, it works fine

Comment: Where's the code for the first query? Are you binding `:title` multiple times there?

Comment: yes the query I've provided in my question is the result of: echo $query;

Comment: it has to be the bind params

Comment: use bindValue()

Comment: look at this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue

Comment: that's ok, do you understand why it worked?

Comment: Yes I guess, bindParam uses call by reference, my query probably looked like c:title='italian' OR c.title='italian' OR c.title='italian', bindValue uses call by Value though. Am I right?