# MySQLi recordset will not return results unless URL parameters are hard-coded in the query

Tags: php

Here is my query:

```
    <?php
$WADAplaces = new WA_MySQLi_RS("WADAplaces",$etrendsi,10);
$WADAplaces->setQuery("SELECT places.ID as PlaceID, offices.ID as OfficeID, YEAR(races.Date) as RaceYear, places.Name as PlaceName, offices.Office as Office, races.ID as RaceID, DATE_FORMAT(races.Date, '%M %e, %Y') as RaceDate, races.Ranked, races.WriteIns FROM places join offices on places.ID = offices.PlaceID join races on offices.ID = races.OfficeID WHERE places.ID = ? AND  YEAR(races.Date) = ? ORDER BY races.Date, offices.ID");
$WADAplaces->bindParam("i", "".((isset($_GET["PlaceID"]))?$_GET["PlaceID"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //varPlaceID
$WADAplaces->bindParam("t", "".((isset($_GET["RaceYear"]))?$_GET["RaceYear"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //varRaceYear
$WADAplaces->execute();
?>
```

The URL parameters ARE being passed correctly, but the only way I can get the query to work is if I hard-code the parameters in, like this:

```
 WHERE places.ID = 9 AND  YEAR(races.Date) = 1865 ORDER BY races.Date, offices.ID
```

Then the query works.  This is my URL string, which is recognizing the form fields correctly, and passing them to the URL:  /places_search.php?PlaceID=9&RaceYear=1868&Search=Search

I think the problem has to do with the date field. If I remove the date field from the mix, then it works fine with just the PlaceID URL parameter.  But I'm not sure how to get the date to work.  If I hard-code the date, it works.  Thank you.

Comment: What is `WA_MySQLi_RS`? That's not a standard PHP class.

Comment: If `WA_MySQLi_RS::bindParam()` calls `PDOStatement::bindParam()`, the argument needs to be a variable, not an expression. You need to use `bindValue()` with an expression.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the parameter in the query (date field), and now it's working.  This is what fixed it.  Just removing the isset from the parameter.

```
$WADAplaces->setQuery("SELECT places.ID as PlaceID, offices.ID as OfficeID, YEAR(races.Date) as RaceYear, places.Name as PlaceName, offices.Office as Office, races.ID as RaceID, DATE_FORMAT(races.Date, '%M %e, %Y') as RaceDate, races.Ranked, races.WriteIns FROM places join offices on places.ID = offices.PlaceID join races on offices.ID = races.OfficeID 
WHERE places.ID = ? AND YEAR(races.Date) = ?
ORDER BY races.Date, offices.ID");
$WADAplaces->bindParam("i", "".((isset($_GET["PlaceID"]))?$_GET["PlaceID"]:"")  ."", "-1"); //varPlaceID
$WADAplaces->bindParam("i", "".($_GET['RaceYear'])  ."", "-1");//varRaceYear
$WADAplaces->execute();
```