# Update MySQL with value from SESSION sets NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to bind the parameter "userShort" from my SESSION together with some other values into my pdo statement. But everytime I run it, it updates the user column with a NULL value while all other columns get updated with the correct value. Where is my mistake?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE productionplanning 
                            SET '.$column.' = :value, 
                                lastChange = :timestamp, 
                                user = :worker 
                        WHERE idproductionplanning = :id');

$stmt->bindValue(':value', $value);
$stmt->bindValue(':timestamp', $timestamp);
$worker = $_SESSION['userShort'];
$stmt->bindParam(':worker', $worker, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4);
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
```

When I var_dump my SESSION it shows that userShort really does have a value:

`["userShort"]=> string(2) "MK"`

The column is of the type VARCHAR(4) and I'm calling the UPDATE statement through ajax.
Am I just stupid for not seeing my mistake? Also, I'm pretty new to php/pdo/mysql, so I appreciate every help even if it seems stupid to you.

Comment: Where exactly do you do the var_dump? Did you call session_start on the AJAX page?

Comment: Why are you switching between `bindValue` and `bindParam`?

Comment: @SalmanA I knew it was something stupid. The session_start was missing. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @cBroe I'm stilling trying to figure out the difference between bindValue and bindParam and haven't had time yet to read more detailed about it. But I noticed that with bindValue I get an error while bindParam at least runs through even if the value isn't assigned. Gonna check that as the next step.

Comment: There a question-answer-thread about the difference between the two here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1179874/1427878