# Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\sync\inc\firewall\fw.php.php on line 62

Tags: php

Please I am stucked in solving the above error. I have seen related questions but I can figure out how to handle it. Your help will be highly appreciated.

```
    public function checkAllowedIp() {
    global $pdo;
    $check = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Allowedips WHERE ip = :ip");
    $check->bindParam("ip", $this->getIp());  //line 62
    $check->execute();

    return ($check->rowCount() > 0);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue - If doesn't make sense to use `bindParam()` here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks I have gotten the code to work see below:

```
    public function checkAllowedIp() {
    global $pdo;
    $check = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Allowedips WHERE ip = :ip");
    $jik = $this->getIp();
    check->bindParam('ip',$jik);  //line 62
    $check->execute();

    return ($check->rowCount() > 0);
}
```

Comment: Why not just `bindValue()`?