# Deleting data from a database when a button is clicked

Tags: php, database, delete-row

On a shopping cart, when I click the delete button, the row isn't being deleted from the database, any reason why?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['delete_button'])) {

  $id = $_POST['id'];

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM user_favourites WHERE user_fav_id = :user_fav_id");

  $stmt->bindParam(':user_fav_id', $id);

  $stmt->execute();

  header("Location: index.php?p=account");
  exit();
}
?>
```

And the button code

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $fav['user_fav_id'] ?>">
    <button type="submit" name="delete_button">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I test your code, so by instinct I'd verify few things:

1. Make sure your `$fav['user_fav_id']` is well echoed in your hidden input (a basic inspect the element will do the job) and its value is the one expected
2. Be careful to not modify your variable `$id` between the `bindParam()` and the `execute()` as with [PDOStatement::bindParam()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) unlike [PDOStatement::bindValue()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that [PDOStatement::execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) is called. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179874/what-is-the-difference-between-bindparam-and-bindvalue) for more information
3. Try other DataBase manipulations elsewhere to check if your the link to the DB is not broken

Side note: *Any user can modify the value of the hidden input. If this is is meant to go online, you should rethink how you manage this feature because a user A can delete the favourites of a user B by manipulating this value.*